# How to write an entire list into one csv cell ?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I am currently doing a little web scraping project and am turning the information into a python object.

For example, each scraped instance turns into an object with a title, text, and a list of more text.

I want to turn each element of an item into its own column. How can I write the list of text into a single csv cell?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to just convert the list of text into a *single string* to be added to the single CSV column?

Comment: Well each instance of the list is a response on a forum page so it might get a little tricky making sense of the data when its all bundled into one string

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You have a list of strings, but you want this list represented in a single CSV cell, right? That would basically mean you'd have to lump it together. Once it's written into CSV it's not an object anymore, just text. You could compose it in such a way that you can extract it and convert it back to a list in Python, but it would still just be text.

Comment: gotcha, thanks for the clarification

Comment: You can `join` the list based on a special character (which you are certain is not in any of the responses in the list) and then to extract them you could split on the same character. So: `list.join('|')` and then `stringFromCSV.split('|')`